# Submit form in new page without target="_blank"

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, forms

I have two different buttons that submit the same form. One submits the form and then runs a database query and the other gives you a preview of what the query will look like.

I want the preview to open in a new page, but otherwise for it to open in the same page

Here are my buttons:

```
<input type="button" onclick="ClearField2(); upload();" value="CREATE YOUR CAMPAIGN!" STYLE="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; float: left;" class="btn" />
<div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; float: left;">
<input type="button" onclick="ClearField(); upload();" value="OR PREVIEW FIRST!" STYLE="" class="btn"><br>
```

They both run upload(); which submits the form. `Clearfield();` gives a "true" value to the preview variable and `Clearfield2();` gives a "false" one. True tells it to not run the DB Query and to show the preview where False tells it to run the query and show a success message.

Obviously, to submit the form in a new page I can add target="_blank" to the `<form>` tag, but this forces submission in a new page no matter which button was clicked.

Is there any way to tell it to submit the form in a new page based on which button was clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamically add the `target="_blank"` in your `ClearField` function? You're already using JavaScript, might as well change the form while you're at it.

```
document.getElementById('form_element_id').setAttribute('target', '_blank')
```

Comment: Hmmm let me look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton. I don't think I would have ever thought of that. I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I'm able.